# New GPO using c++ program

Tags: c++, impersonation, group-policy, gpo

I am trying to create gpo programatically using *IGrouppolicyobject* interface

Am running the program in child domain and able to successfully create GPO in child domain.

To create GPO in parent domain, am impersonating (using LogonUser windows function) the parent Domain Admin credential

(impersonation is success and am using LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS in LogonUser method to impersonate and even the subsequent ImpersonateLoggedOnUser method also success)

But the gpo creation call (IGrouppolicyobject's New method) fails with Access Denied error code: 80070005

Kindly guide me.

Here is the code..

```
HANDLE tokHandle = NULL;
BOOL chk = LogonUser("parent domain admin name", "parent domain name", "password", LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, &tokHandle);
if(chk) {
    chk = ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(tokHandle);
    if(!chk)
    {
        //print error code in log
    }
    CloseHandle(tokHandle);
}
else
{
    //print error code in log
}
if(chk) {
    IGroupPolicyObject* gpo = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_GroupPolicyObject, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGroupPolicyObject, (LPVOID*)&gpo);
    if (hr==S_OK) {
        hr = gpo->New(L"LDAP://dcname/DC=domain,DC=com", L"gponame", GPO_OPEN_READ_ONLY);
        if(hr!=0) {
            print hr;   //ACCESS DENIED ERROR CODE COMES HERE...
        }
    } else {
        //print error code in log
    }
    if(gpo) gpo->Release();
    RevertToSelf();
}
```

Comment: Where's your code?  See [ask].

Comment: updated code in question

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer based on what I quickly noticed in the code.  It is seen sometimes where certain variables aren't updated, not sure if that was the case for you but if it is, it would be an easy fix, based on just confirming them with your Active Directory Administrator.

Comment: Hi Heron, i hope the problem is not related to variable updation and all.. code is working to create gpo in child domain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer.

Seems `IGroupPolicyObject` new method is mistakenly reverting the impersonation done in the calling thread. So only the impersonation is not taking place. So created a new process with the required credentials to accomplish my task.

Reference: https://shellexecute.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/igrouppolicyobjectnew-will-fail-if-thread-is-impersonating-or-identity-or-delegation/